# remove special character and space from string using php

Tags: php

I have one array and I will pass `key` as `array[0]` value but values are like below and i want to remove last `:` and `space`

**problem :**

```
[Type of company: ]
```

I want like

```
[Type of company]
```

I tried following string function

```
rtrim() 
preg_replace()
str_replace()
```

but it did not work

how to get that desired output

Comment: remove `:` and `space` from last

Comment: `rtrim(': ]') . ']'`

Comment: try this `var_dump(rtrim($array[0],': '));`

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
substr(yourstring, 0, -2);
```

Answer (score 0):

### [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) both work just tested,

```
$arr = ['Type of Company: ', 'Testing: ', 'Something else: '];


foreach($arr as $val) {
    /** rtrim($val, ': '); **/
    echo str_replace(': ', '', $val) . '<br>';    
}
```

**Output**

```
Type of Company
Testing
Something else
```

Most likely your usage is incorrect, ensure that the parameters are being passed in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

simple use `rtrim()`

```
<?php

$array = array('Type of companys: ');

var_dump(rtrim($array[0],': '));

?>
```